# Send a video radio signal via a PC to a portable VHF/UHF TV

Tags: rf, radio, video-transmitter

I‘m trying to build an art installation. I want to send a video radio signal via my PC to an old portable TV.

My idea was it to run a HDMI cable to a D/A converter and run a software that lets me send the signal over an appropriate frequency with low power so as not to interfere with anything in my broad surrounding. I could then tune into that signal with the TV.

I’m quite sure it’s not that simple, but I’m eager to learn.

How would I go about it?

Links, instructions, and criticism are welcome.

Comment: In most countries (and without a radio amature license) doing this would be illegal and result in you getting a visit from the regulator followed by a fine.  the UHF bands that used to be for TV are now often split between digital TV and mobile telephony.

Comment: You could emulate the situation using a WIFI radio extender and a TV modulator, this would send the video but at a legal frequency, with the UHF part being over a cable.

Comment: Regardless, "how do I do my whole project" questions aren't suitable for the Q&A sites in the Stack Exchange network. Questions need to be specific.

Comment: Just use a WiFi video decoder attached to the portable.

Comment: https://thorbroadcast.com/es/producto/petit-hdmi-rf-modulator-1.html

Comment: @JayM using that I could also connect the Modulator to the TV with an Antenna cable?

Comment: @Lundin would you have a alternative site I could use? 
And what would I need to be more specific of? 
Greetings

Comment: If the TV has composite input you can buy any suitable device you like to transfer composite wirelessly, or generate it directly with a small computer at the TV. If it has only RF input, add a modulator. This isn't an electronics design question, it's more like what electronic devices can be used to accomplish the task.

Comment: I'd give this user some slack.   He is new to SE and even I can't think of a better place to ask this question given the knowledge of those in this site compared to elsewhere, perhaps this should be moved to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ however I am not sure that place has so much in-depth domain knowledge.

Comment: @JayM
I’ll wait a bit to see, if that‘s the best recommended site. Thank you!

Comment: See https://www.circuits-diy.com/tv-video-transmitter-circuit-vhf-uhf/ for a simple uhf transmitter. Composite in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using suggestions e.g. 'a D/A converter' in your question requires very in-depth knowledge of electronics, RF design and signal processing.  It would be a very complicated thing to do even for an expert in all those fields.  However off the shelf products that do that for you are already available.

It should be noted that due to the way it works, legacy analog TV is very limited in what it can do compared to what can travel down a HDMI cable and hence what people have come to expect in video quality. For example in the UK colour analog broadcast TV was limted to 625 lines (in reality a little less) at 50 (half frames) per second, interlaced where only 312.5 lines were updated per 25Hz frame.  Horizontally this was about 500 to 600 'pixels'. Though as this was analog, pixels were not really transmitted.  That is very low quality compared to modern digital HDTV standards with 3840 × 2160 being a typical UHD resolution. UK analog TV was turned off completely in 2012 and the VHF/UHF broadcast spectrum re-allocated.

Hence any system based on this answer would be very low quality compared to what people expect.  However for the purpose of art (as per the question)  this may be what is desired.  With some simple video processing on the PC typical analog TV imperfections (that in the day we just accepted) could even be emulated.

Assumptions:

- Your video source is a PC or similar device with a HDMI output.
- The TV is '*old school*' and only has a UHF input (VHF in some countries).

Example solution (example only, not a recomendation of specific products or suppliers):

1. Use a 'WIFI' (though should really be called a [2.4G ISM band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_radio_band)*)
   extender, e.g. [Like one of these.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/EVanlak-Generrtion-Passthrough-Eliminated-Thunderbolt-HDMI-EDID-1080-2P/dp/B07YMTGV2S)
   [image]
2. Plug one of these into your video source, e.g. the PC
3. Plug the other into a UHF modulator with a HDMI input like [one of
   these.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Modulator-Video-Source-1080p-Channels-Black/dp/B07RQN6XRS) (though I am sure there are cheaper alternatives)
   [image]
4. And cable that to the back of the TV using a [coaxial cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_aerial_plug).
   [image]

* Though there is no reason it could not, it's unlikely that a WIFI video extender uses [WIFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) ([802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)) protocols, so it's not strictly correct to use the term WIFI even though such products often do.

Comment: What would be the use of the ‚WIFI‘ extender?

Comment: @cosi the extender transmits hdmi over the 2.4.ghz unlicensed range (which older wifi uses). It's a way to get your video transmitted wirelessly.

Comment: @passerby Thanks for the circuit as it is relevant to the question. Though it should be noted that this does not work on TV transmission all countries, depending on the modulation scheme being used and how the synchronisation pulses are encoded.  It also omits any colour or sound sub-carrier channels.

Comment: UHF and VHF are frequency bands. The connection is RF.

Comment: @codebeat I don't understand what that comment adds, please elaborate?

Comment: The standard VHF/UHF channels are between 2 and 69 or 54 MHz to 902 MHz. 
How could the 2,4 GHz connect to that?

Comment: @JayM An input type is not a frequency band. The input used is RF.